# Clearing timeouts with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, timeout

i'm having some sort of variable out of scope issue or something. in the function below, i'm creating or clearing a timeout based on whether the mouse is entering or exiting. it seems though, that even once the timeout has been created it's returning undefined on re-entry. not sure what i'm doing wrong here, thanks for your help!

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ByuG3/)

JavaScript: (particular issue is within `else` conditional on line 35

```
var navLinks = $('nav li.sub');

navLinks.mouseenter(function(){

  console.log('hovering on link');

  var thiis   = $(this),
      subList = thiis.find('ul'),
      autoClose;

  if (!thiis.hasClass('out')){

    console.log('isnt out');

    /* Link */

    thiis

    /* Show submenu when entering link */

    .addClass('out')

    /* Hide submenu when exiting link */

    .mouseleave(function(){

      autoClose = setTimeout(function(){

        thiis.removeClass('out');
      }, 1000);


      console.log('exiting link: timeout active', autoClose);
    });
  } else {

    console.log ('is out', autoClose);

    if (autoClose){

      console.log('is out: clear timeout');

      clearTimeout(autoClose);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As written, `var autoClose` ensures that `autoClose` is local to the `mouseenter` handler, *each time it fires*. If you want to `clearTimeout(autoClose)` from a previous `mouseenter` event, then you must place `var autoClose` in an outer scope. Thus the same `autoClose` will be available to every execution context of the event handler and can be set/cleared as necessary.

Comment: try to wrap it like `navLinks.each(function () { var autoClose; $(this).mouseenter(/**/); });`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot got it- make it an answer, i'd like to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Techno,

The simple answer is just to move `var autoClose` to an outer scope, but I think you can (and should) do more.

More specifically,

- I don't think you want to attach the `mouseleave` handler inside the `mouseenter` handler. It can be permanently attached from the outset.
- In the `mouseenter` handler, `clearTimeout(autoClose)` and `thiis.addClass('out')` can be executed unconditionally. There's no real economy in testing `.hasclass('out')`.

Try this :

```
var navLinks = $('nav li.sub');
var autoClose;
navLinks.hover(function(){
    var thiis = $(this);
    clearTimeout(autoClose);
    thiis.addClass('out');
}, function(){
    var thiis = $(this);
    autoClose = setTimeout(function(){
        thiis.removeClass('out');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: worth mentioning that within the timeout $(this) refers to the window, so best to set a variable of the navLink similar to the mouseenter implementation. also, for shorthand, can now use the .hover() method for shorthand of both: .hover(function(){}, function(){});

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments to question you have new timeout each time mouse hovers an item. Lets make new timeout variable for every item:

```
$('nav li:has(ul)').each(function(){
  var par = $(this),
      sub = $("> ul", this),
      closeTO;

  par.hover(
    function(){
      clearTimeout(closeTO);
      par.addClass("out");
    },
    function(){
      closeTO = setTimeout(function(){
        par.removeClass("out");        
      }, 1000);
    }
  );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ByuG3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global object to store some vars like reference of timeout and interval.
In example you could declare such an object:

```
// Declare the context object in the global scope
var myContext = {
    "myTimeout" : false
}
```

And then use the context object in your mouseenter and mouseleave handler functions.